# On Linux - How do I get an HDD serial number of a specific partition?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, serial-number

I need to create a tool that once launched at some directory should print the HDD serial number that the directory exists in.

Is there any way on Linux (e.g. Ubuntu 16.10) to get the HDD SN by path /dev/... ?

I've tried various tools (lsblk, hdparam, ...) but haven't succeeded.

Comment: `hdparm -I /dev/sda|grep "Serial Number"` won't do ?

Comment: Are you wanting to find the physical device parameters from the starting point of a known partition path?

Comment: @ pawel7318 have tried that, the output is SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]: 70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 c0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 000 00 00 00 00. Doesn't seem to be correct :(

Comment: @ Kerry correct, I need to know the HDD sn that the app is launched from

Comment: Your question is still not well constructed. Lay out the problem before the sharing the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Describe [step like these](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-debug-any-problem-ac6f8a867fae) that you have done thus far, for code, conditions, and errors. State 'obvious' context that you already know, [so that people understand what you have tried](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `df .` to get a device name on which your folder is located. 
Then using a name of your device (will be something like /dev/sda2) you could run this command:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=NAME_OF_DEVICE_FROM_FIRST_COMMAND | grep ID_SERIAL
```

The command in 1 line:

```
df . | tail -1 | awk {'print $1'} | (read name; udevadm info --query=all --name=$name) | grep ID_SERIAL
```

Comment: run `df .` and as you said I got `/dev/sda1`. The second command didn't print out anything

Comment: what output do you get when you run udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda1 ?

Comment: the command in 1 line didn't print out as well. I'm using a virtual machine, whether it could be the reason?

Comment: `udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda1` prints the list. ID_SERIAL isn't there. I believe that could be because of using a virtual machine, couldn't it?

Comment: when I try it in VM I don't get a serial too.

Comment: @ Iurii Drozdov Thanks, got the actual SN at a regular OS